# Resources for Windows Phone 7 development

Tags: silverlight-4.0, xna, windows-phone-7

Windows Phone 7 has been unveiled and MS have announced all [details of the development chain](http://windowsteamblog.com/blogs/wmdev/archive/2010/02/15/windows-phone-7-series-going-big-for-developers-at-mix10.aspx) at the [Mix10](http://www.microsoft.com/events/mix/default.aspx) conference.

So this could be a good starting point/collection of online resources as they appear

EDIT: I've removed the speculation tag now that the covers are off

Comment: Related Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402466/getting-started-with-windows-phone-7

Answer (score 13):

An excerpt from [Programming Windows Phone 7 Series](http://www.charlespetzold.com/phone/index.html) by Charlez Petzold just became available online.

Answer (score 6):

Charlie Kindel has started a [MSDN blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/ckindel/) on WP7 development, along with a [video](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/LauraFoy/First-Look-Windows-Phone-7-Series-Hands-on-Demo/) on Channel9.

windows phone twitter account: [@windowsphone](http://twitter.com/windowsphone)

Answer (score 3):

For WP7/XNA related information, keep an eye on [Shawn Hargreave](http://blogs.msdn.com/shawnhar/)'s blog :-)

Answer (score 2):

Some info leaked and available here: http://www.mobiletechworld.com/2010/02/18/windows-phone-7-series-development-information/

Comment: nice! that looks more concrete than anything else i've seen :)

Answer (score 2):

You can get the newly released Windows Phone 7 Series "SDK" from the  [Windows Phone Developer Home Page](http://developer.windowsphone.com/windows-phone-7-series/)

Click the "Download the Developer Tools" on the right hand side to get the bits.

Answer (score 2):

Remember the Windows Phone 7 version of fousquare from the MIX10 demo?

You can download the source code from http://4square.codeplex.com/.

Answer (score 1):

There's a ton of resources out there for Silverlight, and for the most part all of this applies to Silverlight for Windows Phone. My limited experience so far has been quite postive. I took a simple game I wrote for Silverlight and cut and pasted the XAML and code into a new Windows Phone application and pressed F5. It ran without modification, the only thing I couldn't get working was the sound.

If your interested I just posted the source code on my [blog](http://www.trillian.com.au/2010/03/sample-application-for-windows-phone.html).

Answer (score 1):

For XNA there's a lot of information at [the XNA creators site](http://creators.xna.com/en-US/education/).

The forums are pretty good too [over here](http://forums.xna.com/forums/) combined they cover most aspects of game and app design and publishing.

Worth a visit.

Answer (score 1):

I put together a [list of resources to help people get started on Windows Phone 7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/davedev/getting-started-with-windows-phone-7-resources) that might help as well.

Answer (score 1):

**Jesse Liberty**
[Silverlight and Windows Phone 7 Programming](http://jesseliberty.com/)

Answer (score 0):

the Microsoft Press WP7 book by Charles Petzold is now online [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150819173816/http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/0/A/50A39509-D015-410F-A8F2-A5511E5A988D/Microsoft_Press_ebook_Programming_Windows_Phone_7_PDF.pdf).