# Which are good books to learn WP7 programming?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, expression-blend

Can u please recommend some good books (pdfs) and sites where i could get information on Windows Phone Seven programming.I would also like to know more on Expression Blend also.

Comment: Might be worth keeping these suggestions all in one place. This is the 5th what is a good book question for wp7dev.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting Started with Windows Phone 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402466/getting-started-with-windows-phone-7)

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267229/resources-for-windows-phone-7-development

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find everything here :)

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2010/10/28/free-ebook-programming-windows-phone-7-by-charles-petzold.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Here you can download the PDF [Expression Blend 4 with Silverlight](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/143022973X). I hope it would be useful for knowing about Expression Blend 4.

Comment: It would be nice if you purchase the book, instead of getting it from 'other' links ;)

Answer (score 2):

- [Charles Petzold: Programming Windows Phone 7](http://www.charlespetzold.com/phone/)
- [Rob Miles: Windows Phone Programming in C#](http://www.robmiles.com/journal/2011/1/5/windows-phone-blue-book-pdf.html)
- [UI Design and Interaction Guide for Windows Phone 7](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=183218)
- [Nick Randolph and Christoper Fairburn: Professional Windows Phone 7 Application Development: Building Applications and Games Using Visual Studio, Silverlight, and XNA](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470891661)

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest book from apress about game development
[Windows Phone 7 Game Development](http://apress.com/book/view/1430233060)

Answer (score 0):

[Adam Nathan: 101 Windows Phone 7 Apps](http://www.amazon.co.uk/101-Windows-Phone-Apps-Developing/dp/0672335522/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1305558210&sr=8-1)
This book is simply great: good if you're new to the platform, good if you want to know some tricks, even good just as a refecente and on top of that it's full color and "styled" like the Phone OS :)

Edit: oh i forgot, it's a two volumes manual, the second one will be released this summer