# Mobile Development Tutorial On Microsoft Platform

Tags: windows-phone-7, mobile, windows-mobile

I want to create a mobile application on Microsoft platform, but I dont know how to start developing with the Microsoft Platform. Can anyone tell me where and how to start this task and what I'll need for it (such as IDE, testing devices, etc).

Comment: Did you search for "Windows Phone tutorials"? See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lebanon/archive/2011/08/09/excellent-windows-phone-7-development-tutorials.aspx for example.

Comment: maybe also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267229/resources-for-windows-phone-7-development

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello Brother try this in 31 Days
http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2011/07/31-days-with-wp7-collection-of-windows.html